# \write 18 compilation issue

Tags: errors, compiling

I am submitting my work to a journal. My latex source has several sub files (images) created in latex. I have attached attached all the required files and when the journal's submission system try to create a proof file, the process is aborted with error. When I looked at the generated log file, it shows the following error:***

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3 strings out of 495063
 117 string characters out of 3182200
 45057 words of memory out of 3000000
 3288 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

 STOUT: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode


Command Log results:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2018.11.13)  22 DEC 2018 00:26
**entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.**

**Anonymous+Main+Document.tex
! Emergency stop.
<*> Anonymous+Main+Document.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

I have no problem in compiling the manuscript in my machine and it can generate PDF without any problem. I am not sure what is causing this error and I am also not sure if this is a problem at my side either.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

cheers

Comment: Well, I think the problem is the very outdated TeX distribution from 2013!

Comment: If the outdated version of LaTeX is not the problem, then this will likely be hard to diagnose. I don't expect this to have anything to do with `\write18` (unless you're explicitly using it).

Comment: Indeed the quoted messages don't mention any warning or error at all. The `\write18` message is normal and usually no cause for alarm. Is there any way you can obtain a more detailed log from the submission system? This message is not really helpful in diagnosing anything. Make sure that your document compiles and does not produce any errors or warnings on your machine. (Sometimes people ignore error messages, because their editors are set up to scroll past them.)

Comment: The only thing that can give us a hint is the `! Emergency stop`. That could mean that a file was not found or that the file does not contain an `\end{document}` or similar. Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354518/35864

Comment: What does the + symbols in the file name mean? Are you really using them or do they indicate e.g. spaces in the file name?

Comment: as others have said there is no indication of any `\write18` issue here. I would guess that your original file had spaces in its name and confused the journal's upload system.

Comment: I had the identical problem: TeX file worked fine in my 2019 TexShop but failed on submission to the journal's 2013 version. It was indeed caused by the SPACES IN THE FILENAME. Ulrike Fischer, thanks so much!

Comment: My experiece tells me: 1. Error in tex file  2. write 18 enabled is caused by Mac OS System preference> security and privacy setting. Need to add TeXShop if on macOS.